# EPPlus How to retrieve Excel cell formatting into DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, epplus

how to load from Excel using EPPlus formatting from saved worksheet to DatagridView ?

Place  the data into DatagridView.

```cs
private void importFastExcelCompare(DataGridView dt, string excelFileName,string sheetName)
{
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(excelFileName);
    using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
    {    //create a list to hold all the values
        // get the first worksheet in the workbook
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[sName];
        // Fetch the WorkSheet size
        ExcelCellAddress startCell = worksheet.Dimension.Start;
        ExcelCellAddress endCell = worksheet.Dimension.End;

        for (Int32 row = startCell.Row; row <= endCell.Row; row++)
        {   // place all the data into DataTable
            dt.Rows.Add();
            for (int col = startCell.Column; col <= endCell.Column; col++)
            {
                var excelCell = worksheet.Workbook.Worksheets.First().Cells[row, col];
                var gridViewCell = dt.Rows[row - 1].Cells[col - 1];

               using (var range = excelCell.Worksheet.Cells[row, col, row, col])
                {
                   // gridViewCell.Style.ForeColor = range.Style.Font.Color;
                    //gridViewCell.Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(range.Style.Font.Color);
                }
                gridViewCell.Value = excelCell.Value;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

EPPlus cells has Style property. For example,

```
worksheet.Cells["C2:C5"].Style.Numberformat.Format
```

will give you number format of the cell. 
Similarly, you can access following properties to get more cells formatting.

```
worksheet.Cells["C2:C5"].Style.Font
worksheet.Cells["C2:C5"].Style.Fill 
worksheet.Cells["C2:C5"].Style.Font.Color
```

You can check https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki for more details.

Comment: Yes, I read that. But how to use it? DataGridView.Rows[row - 1].Cells[col - 1].Style.ForeColor = worksheet.Cells["C2:C5"].Style.Font.Color; Compiler error: Cannot implicitly convert type OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFont' to 'System.Drawing.Color'

Comment: You need to type cast it, try this, 
var rgbColor = ws.Cells["C1:C5"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb;
var dataGridColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" + rgbColor); DataGridView.Rows[row - 1].Cells[col - 1].Style.ForeColor = dataGridColor;

Comment: Thank you it works. The other problem is with Font (Bold, Italic, etc.) Is there some example of how to import it cell properties? Saving cell properties was easy to solve  ....

Comment: Try this, 
// EPPlus, Get cell font
var headerFont = headerCells.Style.Font;

// DataGridView, Set cell font
DataGridViewCellStyle style = dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle;
style.Font = new Font(dataGridView1.Font, headerFont.Bold);

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that works for me is to evaluate the font settings separately. Unfortunately, loading will drastically slow down. Maybe there is a better solution ....

```
 private void gridFont(ExcelRangeBase eFont, DataGridViewCell dtCell)
    {
        if (eFont.Style.Font.Bold && eFont.Style.Font.Italic && eFont.Style.Font.UnderLine)
        {
            System.Drawing.Font myFont = new System.Drawing.Font(eFont.Style.Font.Name, eFont.Style.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline | FontStyle.Italic);
            dtCell.Style.Font = myFont;
        }
        else
        { 
        if (eFont.Style.Font.Bold && eFont.Style.Font.Italic)
        {
            System.Drawing.Font myFont = new System.Drawing.Font(eFont.Style.Font.Name, eFont.Style.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);
            dtCell.Style.Font = myFont;
        }
        else
            { 
        if (eFont.Style.Font.Bold && eFont.Style.Font.UnderLine)
        {
            System.Drawing.Font myFont = new System.Drawing.Font(eFont.Style.Font.Name, eFont.Style.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline);
            dtCell.Style.Font = myFont;
        }
        else
           { 
        if (eFont.Style.Font.Italic && eFont.Style.Font.UnderLine)
        {
            System.Drawing.Font myFont = new System.Drawing.Font(eFont.Style.Font.Name, eFont.Style.Font.Size, FontStyle.Italic | FontStyle.Underline);
            dtCell.Style.Font = myFont;
        }
        else
          { 
                  if (eFont.Style.Font.Bold)
                     {

                        System.Drawing.Font myFont = new System.Drawing.Font(eFont.Style.Font.Name, eFont.Style.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
                        dtCell.Style.Font = myFont;
                    }
                else
                        {
                            if (eFont.Style.Font.Italic)
                            {
                                System.Drawing.Font myFont = new System.Drawing.Font(eFont.Style.Font.Name, eFont.Style.Font.Size, FontStyle.Italic);
                                dtCell.Style.Font = myFont;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (eFont.Style.Font.UnderLine)
                                {
                                    System.Drawing.Font myFont = new System.Drawing.Font(eFont.Style.Font.Name, eFont.Style.Font.Size, FontStyle.Underline);
                                    dtCell.Style.Font = myFont;
                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
```